# Select Mysql para Saldo de Kardex

Tags: mysql

Estimado Colegas.
Se requiere de una consulta de la siguiente forma.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Mi pregunta es como tendría que realizar el select para generar el campo saldo.
Gracias por su ayuda.

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si quieres hacerlo en un solo query, necesitas utilizar variables auxiliares. Aquí un ejemplo, considera que debes ejecutar **las 3 sentencias** para obtener el resultado deseado:

```
SET @TOTAL := 0;
SET @ARTICULO := '';
SELECT T.id, T.articulo, T.tipomov, T.cantidad, T.saldo
FROM (
SELECT id, articulo, tipomov, cantidad,
  CASE 
    WHEN (@ARTICULO = '' OR @ARTICULO = articulo) AND tipomov = '01-INGRESO' THEN @TOTAL := @TOTAL + cantidad
    WHEN (@ARTICULO = '' OR @ARTICULO = articulo) AND tipomov = '02-SALIDA' THEN @TOTAL := @TOTAL - cantidad
    WHEN @ARTICULO != articulo AND tipomov = '01-INGRESO' THEN @TOTAL := 0 + cantidad
    WHEN @ARTICULO != articulo AND tipomov = '02-SALIDA' THEN @TOTAL := 0 - cantidad
  END AS saldo,
  @ARTICULO := articulo
FROM kardex
ORDER BY articulo, id
) T;
```

Comment: Excelente funciona, pero en el caso que tenga distintos productos la variable auxiliar sigue sumando no diferencia un producto del otro para volver a reiniciar la suma.

Comment: @EvolutionxD respuesta actualizada.

Comment: Excelente gracias!

Answer (score 1):

excelente sql, pero creo que se puede reducir un poco. Puedes probar con lo siguiente:

**SQL**

establecemos una variable

```
SET @T:0;
```

Creamos sentencia

```
SELECT articulo, tipomov, cantidad, IF(tipomov ='01-INGRESO',(@T:=@T+cantidad),(@T:=@T-cantidad)) AS saldo FROM kardex;
```