# INSERT Mysql para Saldo de Kardex con Trigger

Tags: mysql, select, trigger, insert

compañeros, vi esta publicación

> [Select Mysql para Saldo de Kardex](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/13099/select-mysql-para-saldo-de-kardex)

lo que quiero realizar es insertar el calculo que se realiza

```
SELECT articulo, tipomov, cantidad, IF(tipomov ='01-INGRESO',(@T:=@T+cantidad),(@T:=@T-cantidad)) AS saldo FROM kardex;
```

tengo tres tablas

```
CREATE TABLE `entrada` (
`item` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`articulo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`tipMov` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`cantidad` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL) COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `salida` (
`item` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`articulo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`tipMov` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`cantidad` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL) COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE `stock` (
`id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`articulo` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`tipMov` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8mb4_general_ci',
`cantidad` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
`saldo` INT(11) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`) USING BTREE)COLLATE='utf8mb4_general_ci' ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3;
```

también me arme unos trigger que cada vez que se ingrese en la tabla ENTRADA, SALIDA, automáticamente se registrara en la tabla KARDEX

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `actualizacion_salida` AFTER INSERT ON `salida` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO stock SET item = NEW.item , articulo = NEW.articulo, tipMov = NEW.tipMov, cantidad = NEW.cantidad; END


CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `actualizacion_entrada` AFTER INSERT ON `entrada` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN INSERT INTO stock SET item = NEW.item , articulo = NEW.articulo, tipMov = NEW.tipMov, cantidad = NEW.cantidad;END
```

quiero que el tigger haga esa operacion y lo registre en mi column saldo, hasta ahora lo que tengo es esto:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `actualizacion_entrada` AFTER INSERT ON `entrada`
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN SET @T:= (SELECT cantidad, IF(NEW.tipMov ='01-INGRESO',
NEW.cantidad+cantidad),(NEW.cantidad-cantidad)) FROM stock);
INSERT INTO stock SET item = NEW.item , articulo = NEW.articulo, tipMov = NEW.tipMov, cantidad = NEW.cantidad, saldo = @T;END
```

Answer (score 0):

Bueno no se si es buen practica pero yo lo solucione

```
BEGIN SET @ID:= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM stock);
SET @SALDO_ULT:= (SELECT IFNULL(saldo, 0) FROM stock WHERE id = @ID);
INSERT INTO stock SET item = NEW.item , articulo = NEW.articulo,
tipMov = NEW.tipMov, cantidad = NEW.cantidad,
saldo = IF((SELECT IFNULL(@ID, 0)) = '',NEW.cantidad ,
IF(NEW.tipMov ='01-INGRESO',(@SALDO_ULT+NEW.cantidad),(@SALDO_ULT-NEW.cantidad)));
```

Se me hace dificil programar o manejar los if en mysql, si alguien lo puede hacer con menos codigo seria genial, gracias.